# Prononcer « ent » à la fin d'un mot

Tags: prononciation, conjugaison

Il est très difficile pour moi de comprendre quelles sont les lettres que je dois prononcer et celles que je dois ignorer dans les mots suivants : *se prononcent*, *s'élident*, *devient*, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The famous "*Les poules couvent souvent au couvent*" in Amélie Poulain :-)

I wouldn't bet on a 100% reliable rule, but at least the grammar plural form is mute ("e") and the other form are most often prononcent "en", or "ent'" in case of liaison).

Same for *ils dévient* [*dévier*] vs *il devient* [*devenir*].

Answer (score 8):

*-ent* à la fin d'un mot peut avoir plusieurs prononciations, et comme dans plusieurs langues, il est difficile de savoir laquelle retenir (il existe des poèmes basés sur ce principe en anglais, mais je digresse).

#### La seule règle : les verbes au pluriel

Ainsi qu'expliqué dans plusieurs réponses, s'il s'agit de la terminaison d'un verbe conjugué à la troisième personne du pluriel (ils/elles), *-ent* est muet et ne modifie pas la prononciation du verbe.

Dans le cas d'« ils prononcent », on dira /*il prononce*/<sup>1</sup>. « Elles devaient » se dira /*elle devait*/.

Comme [rappelé par Fabrice](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16492/7224), la présence du T final permet toutefois de faire une liaison qui ne serait pas possible autrement : « ils prononcent au moins ce mot correctement » peut s'énoncer /*il prononce-t-au moins…*/ (ou /*il prononce au moins…*/, l'art des liaisons ayant tendance à se perdre).

#### Autres cas des verbes

Devenir est un verbe du troisième groupe. Parmi les verbes ayant la même prononciation pour *-ent*, on peut noter :

- venir, devenir… et tous ceux ayant le même radical ;
- tenir et ses dérivés (retenir)<sup>2</sup> ;
- je n'ai pas d'autre exemple me venant et personne n'en a proposé en commentaire.

Pour « il devient », *-ent* prend la même prononciation que *-ain* dans *pain* (\ɛ̃\).

À noter que ceci n'est valable qu'à la troisième personne du singulier. Au pluriel, le *-ent* devient à nouveau muet : « ils deviennent » se prononce /*il devienne*/.

#### Noms, adverbes et adjectifs

Comme précisé plus haut, j'ignore s'il s'agit d'une règle, mais plutôt d'un constat : dans les noms, adverbes et adjectifs (p.ex. pertinent, couvent, souvent, pénitent, ...), *-ent* se prononce comme dans *vent* (\ɑ̃\).

---

<sub>1. Je dois toujours apprendre les notations phonétiques, mais celle-ci a l'avantage d'être lisible par ceux qui ont la même lacune que moi.</sub>

<sub>2. Merci à [Circeus](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/926/circeus) pour [le complément](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/prononcer-ent-%c3%a0-la-fin-dun-mot/16488?noredirect=1#comment30740_16496).</sub>

Comment: Qui a dit que la langue française était compliquée... ? C'est pourtant simple (ironie) ! Pour compléter le 2ème point, je pense que l'indice est que "il devient" est singulier. si le mot se termine par "ent" mais est singulier, alors "ent" se prononce. ( ça pourrait être une règle ça non ? :) )

Comment: Une langue vivante est le fruit de son histoire. La richesse (et la complexité) de la langue française vient de celle de son histoire. Ça pourrait être une règle, mais je manque d'exemples/contre-exemples pour m'assurer de la véracité de mes dires, et je préfère éviter d'énoncer des généralités qui pourraient induire en erreur.

Comment: La seule conjugaison où *-ient* rime avec *chien*, c'est spécifiquement la 3e personne du singulier de l'indicatif des verbes *tenir* et *venir*, ainsi que leurs dérivés.

Comment: @Circeus C'est effectivement tout ce qui me vient à l'esprit, mais a-t-on une source pour cette règle, ou s'agit-il d'une déduction empirique de notre part ?

Comment: C'est empirique, j'imagine qu'une vérification dans un dictionnaire de rimes permettrait de confirmer la chose.

Comment: @Circeus Je crains que le dictionnaire de rimes ne donne pas de règle, mais il pourra toujours confirmer ou un infirmer des exemples particuliers. C'est une très bonne idée en cas de doute.

Answer (score 1):

As a native French speaker, I am not sure if there is a rule in order to correctly guess this. However the pronunciation of *prononcent* and *élident* ignore the "nt" and thus should be pronounced "pro-non-ce" and "é-li-de". As usual in French, you do not pronounce the ending "e". In the case of "prononce" it means you will end with an "s" sound.

For "devient", it should be regarded as "en". You will hear regional differences in the specific pronunciation of that syllable. In Quebec, it is pronounced "in" (as in "pain").

Comment: In France, I've always heard "_devient_" (and "_vient_", "_tient_", ...) as \\vjɛ̃\\ (_pain_ = \\pɛ̃\\). There might be slight nuances between regions (as for any sound/word), but I think they're not that important for that case.

Comment: Unsure on the reason for the -1. I am a native French speaker and this answer is accurate.

Comment: I guess the reason is you wrote "should be pronounced as **en**" while, as @Chop commented,  "should be pronounced as **in**" /ɛ̃/ is expected  (although *en* is sometimes pronounced *in* like in *examen*).

Comment: I meant to say that the 't' here had no effect on pronunciation and should be *regarded* as 'en'. Will make the change accordingly to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Lorsque le mot est un verbe conjugué à la 3e personne du pluriel et finit en *ent* on prononce que le *e* (on ignore le *nt*). Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait d'exception mais je ne suis pas sûre, donc pour les mots demandés on prononce « se prononce », « s'élide » et pour *devient* on ignore juste le *t*.

Answer (score 1):

When the verb is conjugated in the je, tu, il/elle, and ils/elles form, you do not pronounce the conjugated endings. In other words, you only pronounce the stem.  For the nous and vous form, you pronounce it the same way it is spelled except you don't really say the z in the vous form, and the s in the nous form. For example, in parlent, you do not pronounce the ent, but you do pronounce the stem which is parl.

So to pronounce se prononcent, you are basically saying se prononce. Same thing for s'élident, devient.

Here is a link that might be helpful: http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/conjugations/

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: Re: _il devient_ (become) / _ils dévient_ (3rd plur., deviate). You're welcome! You did not make any mistake, just underscoring this small difficulty for two different verbs which share a similar spelling in those cases yet with the latter the _ent_ is not sounded. OP is _devenir_ (become). Thanks!